# VSCode "View Problem" Dialog Background Property

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, background-color

I searched through the [VSCode Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color), but was unable to locate any useful documentation that explained what the properties that highlight the background colors for the widget demonstrated in the image below.

[image: View Problem dialog]

What VSCode Theme property modifies the "View Problem" dialogue's background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two hours of isolating individual properties and trying to diagnose the issue, I can confirm that the property that controls the background color of VSCode's "View Problem" dialog is called: `'editorMarkerNavigation.background'`.

I hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't a problems widget, its  a navigation widget, and it helps to communicate important statuses in the current script you have loaded into the editor. It attempts to help you find and locate issues. I find that it is most useful when used inside of a very large code base. It doesn't just relay what problems exist, it can show errors, info, & warnings too.

So the property you suggested colors the majority of the background, but part of the widget is a header, and to change the background color of the header you will also need to use `"editorMarkerNavigationError.headerBackground"`.

###### *This is the full property list for "Marker Navigation Widget".*

```
// @file "./themes/your-vscode-theme.json"

{
    "editorMarkerNavigationInfo.headerBackground": #000000,
    "editorMarkerNavigation.background": #000000,
    "editorMarkerNavigationError.background": #000000,
    "editorMarkerNavigationInfo.background": #000000,
    "editorMarkerNavigationWarning.background": #000000,
    "editorMarkerNavigationWarning.headerBackground": #000000
}
```